# Shareable function in two jquery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Suppose I have 2 jquery files, but they have the same function, I wanted to use a common file where I can import the similar function to be sharable in other files.

e.g

`first.js` file :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    (function($) {
        "use strict";
       
     function add(a, b) {
      return a + b
     }

    })(django.jQuery);
});
```

then another file `second.js` :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        (function($) {
            "use strict";
           
         function add (a, b) {
          return a + b
         }
    
        })(django.jQuery);
    });
```

I wanted to add this similar function `add` in a common file like `common.js` then import it in file `first.js` and `second.js` , how is this done ?

Comment: Also note that the `load` event handler (including the IIFE/closure injecting `django.jQuery`) is unnecessary and can be removed

Comment: Can't this be done without html ? What I mean the code shareability ?

Comment: Are you running the JS server side?

Comment: Yes, it's server side, though, I have some html files though, I thought , I could reorganize the code and I leave the scripts as they are with importing common.js

Comment: Actually the jquery usage is on the models level , e.g :

    ```class Media:
        js = ('admin/js/second.js',)```

Answer (score 0):

place the `code` in `common.js` and in your html or other(like pHp) file import the `common.js` with `script` tag like this `<script src="common.js"></script>`